# .NET: How to deprecate a WebMethod?

Tags: .net, asmx, deprecated, webmethod

In .NET, **is there a standard way to indicate that a web service method has been 
deprecated**?

*To clarify, by 'web service method', I mean a method that has been decorated with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.*

Is standard practice to just use the `[Obsolete]` attribute to mark it as deprecated, just like any other method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; standard practice is to use the `[Obsolete]` attribute for deprecation within .NET.

**EDIT:**

Keep in mind that this will not formally propagate to the WSDL/service as exposed to the consumer. Since WS's are a standard across technologies; the protocol has to be honored. With that in mind your goal of propagating change to the consumer will unfortunately be tied to release notes as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188744/best-practices-to-deprecate-wcf-services). While not ideal it does provide a vehicle for deprecation.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this attribute will make it into the web or service reference?

Comment: No it won't. The idea behind a WS in that there is a protocol in place and all vendors (MS, Axis2, etc...) can support the defined protocol. Obsolete is specific to .NET and would not propagate to the WSDL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188744/best-practices-to-deprecate-wcf-services on deprecation of WCF services which is really a communication effort to your consumer.

Comment: Right. So if Dan wants to communicate to users that the method is no longer supported, marking it `[Obsolete]` accomplishes? (Not that I'm arguing against marking it, but I merely feel the answer is incomplete in light of the question.)

Comment: @Dan: there is none. The concept of deprecation does not exist in WSDL.